# Can node.js request php file as its endpoint on the same file system, not an http request?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and am building a chat appication that is running inside an existing PHP application. I am using expressjs and also postman-request module. I can easily hit absolute urls but when I try to request a file that lives on my own file system, it fails. I have watch tutorials and read the docs and it seems like the only examples ever shown are how to hit external urls.. I can't imagine that it is not possible to hit files that reside on your own file system.

Here is code below: (in my main index.js server file)

```
const request   = require('postman-request');
const url = 'utils/config.php'; // this file merely echos out a json encoded string.
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response 
      console.log('body:', body); 
    });
```

Here is the error message:
error: Error: Invalid URI "utils/config.php"

This is the file structure:

```
-node_modules
-public
-src
    -utils
        -config.php
  index.js (start for node.js - inside src folder)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting refers to requesting a file from a webserver. Here, you're trying to request a file path, while the computer thinks is a non-existent URL. The PHP file is just text. It doesn't mean anything to the computer, and the PHP interpreter is what runs the PHP code. You aren't running a PHP server in this case, and you're requesting a file path, not a URL.

You have to start a PHP server first, using the [`php`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) command. Make sure to pass in the URL (for example, `localhost:8080/config.php`), and not the file path.

If you wanted to do it entirely from the Node script, you could start a server, request the URL, and then stop the server. It would be possible to use the `spawn` function from the built-in `child_process` module ([refer here](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/)). You could also use `exec`, but this is probably unnecessarily harder.

Comment: Thanks, yes this makes sense. I just thought it should work since the folder where i ran the npm init, is on an apache server that is running PHP outside of that folder. So the node app is just a folder inside of an existing active running php application. I did look into using child_processes but read that they are very heavy resource wise, so I decided to try and find another way. Maybe I will have to just have the paths hit the fully qualified domain path as you recommended.